# Fail to write the message into WebSphere MQ V5.3

Tags: mq

I am getting below exception when am trying to write the message in MQ (V 5.3)

> MQJE001: Completion code '2' Reason '2059'

Please tell me how to disable the channel authentication?

> Caused by:com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException:cc=2:RC=2059;AMQ9503: channel negotiation failed.[3=CLIENT.TO.QM1]

Answer (score 1):

First, I will state the obvious that MQ v5.3 is severely out of date and should be upgraded.  Have you tried setting MQSNOAUT to yes?  That will disable **all** security checks for the queue manager. 
See MQ Infocenter for details and also note that when OAM is removed, it cannot be put back on an existing queue manager. 
http://129.33.205.81/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q013560_.htm

Comment: Yes i have set the environment variable and create the QM even though its not working . Even i can not put the message from local using my channel . Any way thank you for your comment .